в методе os.popen вместо русских букв выводятся знаки вопроса
если в пути есть русские буквы, то команда
os.popen('cd').read()

выводит просто C:\Users\????????..... что только не пробовал:

для начала вводить os.system('chcp 65001'), но тогда тоже нарушалась кодировка или что то еще
пробовал заменить команду cmd 'cd' на что то другое, но все равно выводилось как то не то
пробовал выводить os.popen('chcp 65001 && cd').read() и с '&'

ну короче ничего не получилось, можете помочь решить эту проблему

Если ты считаешь, что вопрос не является дубликатом - добавь больше информации, скриншоты, примеры вывода, что получаешь при разных попытках

А, самое главное не уточнил - как вы код запускаете, где вы этот вывод видите? Потому что может оказаться, что конкретно ваш эмулятор терминала вообще не поддерживает кириллицу.

vs code с помощью os.popen('cd').read(), вижу в консоли

@wanderer если используете расширение code runner - удалите его, будет нормально выводить во встроенный терминал, и большая часть советов начнут работать.

Точно узнать кодировку можно командой print(os.popen('chcp').read()) или в CMD через chcp. Если символы будут сломаны, то числа скорее всего останутся:

При кодировке 866 работает следующий код:
os.popen('cd').read().encode('cp1251').decode('cp866')

Кодируем через encode('cp1251'). После через decode('cp866') декодируем строку (нужно выставить ту кодировку, что получена на 1 шаге).

import os decode = os.popen('chcp').read() decode = decode[decode.index(':')+2:len(decode)-1] print(decode) print(os.popen('cd').read().encode('cp1251').decode(f'cp{decode}'))
выводится:
437
C:\Users????????.....

Посмотрите прикрепленный ответ от insolor - здесь. В нём расписано больше чем у меня - например, способ работы через subprocess. Если это не поможет, то либо кодировки перебирать, либо работать с путем без кириллицы.
